# how to store datagridview cell value before delete?

Tags: c#

how to store datagridview cell value before delete?
error for below code.

```
 private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
           string quant ;
           quant = this.dataGridView1.item.Cells[1].Value.ToString();


            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting problem in deleting multiple rows at delete button click?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] rowindex = new int[dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count]
     for (int iRow=0;iRow<dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;iRow++)
          rowindex[iRow] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[iRow].Index;

foreach (int iRowIndex in rowindex)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(iRowIndex);
}
}
```